# SetHandleInformation failed with error code ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (5)

Tags: winapi, windows, device-driver

My code opens a virtual NIC device using CreateFile. After that I am calling SetHandleInformation on the handle returned by CreateFile to avoid leaking the handle to child processes. The problem is, SetHandleInformation fails with error code 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED). 
Following is the piece of code where I am opening the device and calling SetHandleInformation:

```
handle = CreateFile(dev_name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,NULL);  
if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {  
    if (!(SetHandleInformation(handle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))) {
        printf("SetHandleInformation error, code: %u\n", GetLastError());
    }
}
```

I am observing this failure on Windows 10. My application is running with Administrator privileges. I am able to successfully use the handle for read and write even after this failure, which indicates that CreateFile is working fine.

What could be the possible reason of this failure? I could not find much information on SetHandleInformation failure with error code 5.

Comment: *NtSetInformationObject* return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` only in case handle is invalid. but *SetHandleInformation* first call *NtQueryObject* which return `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE` in this case. possibility that handle will be closed between  this 2 calls very low. and you say that you can use this handle late. very strange. and your handle have no `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` from begin. this flag will be set on handle only if you will be use *bInheritHandle==true* in *SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES*, but you not use this. so call *SetHandleInformation* no have sense in this case, but must not fail anyway

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the above comment by RbMm is correct. To clarify the first statement, in practice `NtSetInformationObject` should only return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` for an invalid handle because no object type denies the right to set the `OBJ_INHERIT` handle attribute, i.e. no type's `TypeInfo.InvalidAttributes` field includes `OBJ_INHERIT`. The normal access pattern (query, update, set) should catch an invalid handle in `NtQueryObject` before calling `NtSetInformationObject`.

Comment: @eryksun - some new objects in latest win10 build denied `OBJ_INHERIT` (*ActivityReference*, *PowerRequest*, *PcwObject*) but even for this objects `NtSetInformationObject` return 0 when we try set `Inherit` to true, (it simply nothing change in handle attributes). and return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` on invalid handle instead `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE` very strange behavior, but even this not explain `SetHandleInformation` return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if no any mistakes here. i can not reproduce this (even with not iheritable object types)

Comment: @RbMm, formerly this strange status value was due to the callback design with a boolean return value. To set handle attributes, the WRK and ReactOS call  [`ExChangeHandle`](https://git.reactos.org/?p=reactos.git;a=blob;f=reactos/ntoskrnl/ex/handle.c;hb=86ba9e6212930acc99193312893d26e2e2ffde44#l1147) with a callback to [`ObpSetHandleAttributes`](https://git.reactos.org/?p=reactos.git;a=blob;f=reactos/ntoskrnl/ob/obhandle.c;hb=86ba9e6212930acc99193312893d26e2e2ffde44#l1837), which returns false if the type disallows setting `OBJ_INHERIT`, in which case the request returns `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, i of course look WRK first. anyway this strange for me - i think need return `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE` in case not valid handle and `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` in case `OBJ_INHERIT` is invalid attribute. then i look win10 binary code - was little changed - in case `InvalidAttributes & OBJ_INHERIT` - function do nothing but return .. `STATUS_SUCCESS`. also i test this on *ActivityReference* object. attribute not set, but no error in call. very strange design. but all this not explain OP error.

Comment: @RbMm, I agree it should return `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE`, but then the callback design would have to be different instead of using a `BOOLEAN`. I think they're depending on the normal pattern (query info, modify info, set info) that catches the invalid handle beforehand in `NtQueryObject`. (Yes, this is a sideline discussion on a tangential topic. It's certainly not related to the OP's problem, which I cannot explain given the limited information presented in the question.)

Comment: anyway file handles is inheritable. and for query or set handle attributes we not need any special access for handle. any access is ok. and not need any privileges. so error can be only in case invalid handle. but OP say that after this he can read and write with this handle. something not converge

Comment: Any chance this is being caused by your anti-virus software?

Comment: @RbMm, when the user calls SetHandleInformation, does the device driver for the object in question get called at any point?  Might it be returning the access denied error, or some other error that gets converted to access denied?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - the device driver not called here at all. all is done by *Ob* subsystem. src can be looked in wrk (compare with win10 exist little different)

Comment: [`ObSetHandleAttributes`](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ob/obquery.c#L572) called from [here](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ob/obquery.c#L730) in [`NtSetInformationObject`](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ob/obquery.c#L655). and in win 10 [`ObpSetHandleAttributes`](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ob/obquery.c#L1771) at this [line](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ob/obquery.c#L1815) now not return error, but do nothing

Comment: Instead of using `SetHandleInformation()`, have you tried using the `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` parameter of `CreateFile()`, setting its `bInheritHandle` field to FALSE?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - `bInheritHandle` is false by default, only when `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` is present and `bInheritHandle` is true - the flag `OBJ_INHERIT` is used for object. so OP code have no sense (call `SetHandleInformation` in this case). but `SetHandleInformation` anyway must not fail, if handle is correct. even more `SetHandleInformation` always first call `NtQueryObject` first and if it fail return error from here. and if ok - call `NtSetInformationObject`. the last api return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` only on invalid handle. but in this case `NtQueryObject` must fail first

Comment: with `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE`. i can not reproduce this kind of error. or may be this on latest win 10 builds where something changed here. i look up to 15063.13 build

Comment: @RbMn: if `CreateFile()` returns a `HANDLE` that is not inheritable by default, then the OP should not need to be call `SetHandleInformation()` to set `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT=FALSE` to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! Since I am passing lpSecurityAttributes as NULL to CreateFile, I have removed the call to SetHandleInformation call.

Comment: @ArunKaushal - anyway very interesting why `SetHandleInformation` return such error. which win 10 build ? this error is stable returned in any program, which containing say only this 2 api call ? for any file handle (not only on this device) ?